# Locate Handwritten Notes within Text-Based Image

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, handwriting-recognition

I have a scanned pages that are mostly typed text with some occasional handwriting (either between paragraphs or in the margins).  What approach can I use to locate the region where handwriting exists?  Said differently, I need to find the **coordinates of the bounding box** where the handwriting is located.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: M.b. use selection by:
1. Color selection (in HSV color space)
2. Size. Handwriting size is greater than the print symbols. Math. morphology, labeling.
3. The line thickness of handwriting is greater than the thickness of letters. Math. morphology

Answer (score 0):

you can label images with this kind of data using googles object detection API using tensor flow, try and use faster rcnn model for accuracy, construct your training data using these kind of images(shown in your query) and labelling the part that you want to detect , after training data is done use that data to make detections and based on that detection you will get bounding boxes for which you can get co-ordinates very easily if you are working with googles tensor flow object detection API

check this link for more detailed and complete process :

https://youtu.be/Rgpfk6eYxJA